# What to use for realtime data?

Tags: android, service, timertask

I am building an app in which I want to monitor sound loudness by using the SoundMeter. See [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/SoundMeter.java).

But what the `getMaxAmplitude()` does is returns the amplitude value only when called.

Now I only need to get the value constantly in realtime(maybe a slight dealy. max 1s) and show it in a textview. But I am confused how to call the method properly.
Should I use :

1. Timer task
2. Asynctask with timer
3. Service or IntentService
4. AlarmManager

And please also mention how to call the method.

Please keep in mind that data gathering may run for a very long time. So I don't want to drain battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlarmManager has a strict restriction to be used with a delay of at least 15 seconds. So that is out of the question. Using a service for such a job seems rather tedious to the phone and overall inappropriate considering we require quick results. Timer task is usually used for timeouts, i.e. bigger delay values. This leaves us with Asynctask. Which I guess, seems like a good choice for your implementation.

About the method. Now this can be done in a few ways. Note that these completely depend on your logic though. Firstly, you can try sending the integer you get from getMaxAmplitude() to the AsyncTask in a loop. You can add a small delay inside the loop to make sure that the asynctask gets completed while you are here. Or you can simply call the method from inside the Asynctask (keeping it private). Rest is up to you and the logic you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But can you show how to call the method and get the value per interval inside Asyctask?

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I did edit the answer.